# Delphi 6 create new form with constructor

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi and have a problem with creating a new form dynamically. I want to create the new form with the elements properties from the gui I made. Here is the form I want to dynamically create :

```
unit AddEmployeeF;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TAddEmployee = class(TForm)
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    AddName: TLabel;
    AddDept: TLabel;
    AddPhone: TLabel;
    AddExtension: TLabel;
    AddDetails: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
    procedure CancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
 private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    constructor CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent; Dummy: Integer = 0); override;
  end;
var
  AddEmployee: TAddEmployee;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
      constructor TAddEmployee.CreateNew(AOwner: TComponent; Dummy: Integer = 0; Detail : String);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  AddDetails.Caption := Detail;
end;


procedure TAddEmployee.CancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    self.Close;
end;

end.
```

I dont want to create all the gui elements again in the constructor, just to modificate some properties of the elements, like caption but keep the positions and other properties from the gui definition. It's possible? And how to create the form from another form, like this? :

```
procedure TWelcome.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
myForm :TAddEmployee;
begin
        myForm := TAddEmployee.CreateNew(AOwner, Dummy, Details);

     myForm.ShowModal;

end;
```

Answer (score 8):

You overrode the wrong constructor.  The `TForm.CreateNew()` constructor bypasses DFM streaming, so all of your design-time components will not be created at run-time.  Worse, your overridden `CreateNew()` constructor is calling the inherited `TForm.Create()` constructor, which calls `CreateNew()` internally, thus you will get stuck in an endless loop that causes an stack overflow error at runtime.

To do what you are asking for, override the `TForm.Create()` constructor instead, or define a whole new constructor that calls `TForm.Create()` internally.  Do not involve `TForm.CreateNew()` at all.

```
type
  TAddEmployee = class(TForm)
    ...
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; // optional
    constructor CreateWithDetail(AOwner: TComponent; Detail : String);
  end;

constructor TAddEmployee.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  CreateWithDetail(AOwner, 'Some Default Value Here');
end;

constructor TAddEmployee.CreateWithDetail(AOwner: TComponent; Detail : String);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  AddDetails.Caption := Detail;
end;
```

```
procedure TWelcome.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myForm : TAddEmployee;
begin
  myForm := TAddEmployee.CreateWithDetail(AOwner, Details);
  myForm.ShowModal;
  myForm.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

Declare your constructor like this:

```
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; const Detail: string); reintroduce;
```

Implement it like this:

```
constructor TAddEmployee.Create(AOwner: TComponent; const Detail: string);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  AddDetails.Caption := Detail;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
myForm := TAddEmployee.Create(MainForm, Details);
```

I'm not sure what you want to pass as the owner. Could be the main form, could be something else.

You should also remove the global variable named AddEmployee and so force yourself to take control over instantiating the form.

I chose to name my constructor Create, and so hide the inherited constructor of that name, to force consumers of the class to supply the Details parameter in order to make an instance of the class.

Comment: Since `TCustomForm` already has a constructor named `Create()`, you will have to declare your custom `Create()` constructor with the `reintroduce` modifier or else you will get a `W1010 Method 'Create' hides virtual method of base type 'TCustomForm'` warning.

Comment: @Remy Thanks, I missed that.